# Parameter initialization in a genetic algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, genetic-algorithms

I'm using a neural network in a genetic algorithm. The neural network has 4 inputs (values between `0` and `1`) and `4` outputs, corresponding to the probabilities of different actions. The neural network has 58 parameters.

At first, I create a random population: each individual has 58 random parameters. Parameters are chosen randomly with the default method of Keras, on python (values between `-1` and `1`). Is it a good method? Maybe the best solution needs to have parameters with values higher than `1` for example, but with my method, only values between `-1` and `1` exist in the "gene pool". So, parameters equal to 3.4 can't appear for example.

I tried to train the same neural network with labeled data and gradient descent, in order to have an idea of the range of the parameter. After training the model, I obtained some parameters with values `>1`, or `<-1`. I thought I could use those parameters as initialization for my genetic algorithm. But how could I get different individuals? If the 1st parameter of my trained model equals 2.5, do I have to set the 1st parameter of the different individuals to `2.5 +- 20%` for example?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should make the range as large as possible (to a reasonable extent) for the first random initialization.

The genetic algorithm will converge to the appropriate range eventually, but giving it a narrow range could result in a sub-optimal solution because the algorithm doesn't have any way to reach a better solution. The only downside of a large range is that it might take a bit longer (more generations) to converge.

So I would suggest you keep a completely random initialization of the values, for instance in the range [-10,10].